# How to ignore hidden files in python functions?

Tags: python

While using os.path.getsize() and os.path.isfile, my script returns the .DS_Store file too which I do not need. How do I ignore those?

```
import os

root = "/Users/Siddhartha/Desktop/py scripts"
for item in os.listdir(root):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
        print item
```

Comment: `item.startswith(".")`?

Comment: Are you trying to ignore just `.DS_Store`, anything that's considered "hidden" by Finder, anything that's considered "hidden" by Finder or its equivalent on every platform, …?

Comment: Or maybe it's a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284115/cross-platform-hidden-file-detection/6365265#6365265 instead, depending on the answer to that question.

Comment: I was just trying to ignore .DS_Store. And I agree, it is a duplicate I didn't find those answers when I tried searching for them though.

Comment: If you're just trying to ignore `.DS_Store` why not just `if item != '.DS_Store':`? That avoids having to define exactly what you want "hidden files" to mean (and how you want it to work on other platforms, etc.) and then implement it, which is a much harder problem than just "ignore .DS_Store files".

Comment: Meanwhile, the accepted answer on the latter dup refers to an open source project that apparently no longer exists, so… I'm not sure what to do…

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you want to ignore all files that start with `.`:

```
import os

root = "/Users/Siddhartha/Desktop/py scripts"
for item in os.listdir(root):
    if not item.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
        print item
```

Comment: Oh I see. Do hidden files always begin with a period? Thanks!

Comment: On some operating systems that is the case, but not for Windows.  For a more generic solution see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6365265/505154

Comment: It's also not true for Mac OS X, which is the case the OP cares about. Files can be hidden at the filesystem level with attributes. And then, on top of that, as far as NSOpenPanel (or Finder.app) is concerned, they can be hidden at the Finder Info level, or by implicit rules like "don't show "~/Library" (in 10.7+), etc.