# Ignoring windows hidden files with python glob

Tags: python, windows, macos, glob

I am moving some files with a python script.   The script should work on both osx and windows.

I am using the the glob module to select the files.   Filter out directories with isfile method from os.path.   The glob module automatically ignores unix . files but it seems that it does grab some windows hidden files.   I have added code to remove one "desktop.ini"  that seems to have appeared in windows.

Are there any other Windows files that might appear or is there a way to ensure that I do not select hidden files in Windows?

```
files = glob.glob('*')
files = filter(os.path.isfile, files)  # filter out dirs
if "desktop.ini" in files : files.remove('desktop.ini')
# then using "shutil.move" to actually move the files
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross platform hidden file detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284115/cross-platform-hidden-file-detection)

Comment: Does this answer help? (Windows only API) http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063074/233608

Comment: thanks got some pointers from links.  Feels a bit convoluted though.  Hoped that the glob module would have some platform independent magic in there.

Comment: Jason R. Coombs's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284115/cross-platform-hidden-file-detection can used for cross platform  added some code to do that.   Scoured glob documentation to no avail, but I suspect it is a unix tool so it is not very friendly with windows use.  Should I delete question? @PiotrDobrogost

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Formic](http://www.aviser.asia/formic).

```
from formic import FileSet
fileset = FileSet(directory="/some/where/interesting",
              include="*.py",
              exclude=["desktop.ini", ".*", "addition", "globs", "here"]
              )
for filename in fileset:
    # use shutil to move them
```

This is a Python library using Globs, but i) already understands most hidden files (list of builtins [here](http://www.aviser.asia/formic/doc/api.html#formic.formic.get_initial_default_excludes)), and ii) allows you to specify any files to exclude from the results ([documentation](http://www.aviser.asia/formic/doc/api.html#formic.formic.FileSet))

Disclosure: I am the maintainer.