# openpyxl - Check if worksheet is hidden

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a large number of excel files and I only want to work with sheets which are not hidden and I want to ignore all hidden sheets.

Currently my python script loops through every sheet regardless of whether or not it's hidden. Is there a simple way to check if a worksheet is hidden?

I've looked online but the only thing I can find is ways to hide/unhide worksheets which I don't want to do here.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284115/cross-platform-hidden-file-detection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ws.sheet_state` to find out whether the worksheet is `hidden` or `visible`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"your_excel.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename=path)

for i in wb.worksheets:
    if i.sheet_state == "visible":
        #do what you need to...
```