# Visibility of dataframe. - Pandas Python

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, visibility, import-from-excel

```
df = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsb", sheet_name="sheetname")
```

Is it possible to check the df (DataFrame) visibility.

I have read the excel file (.xlsb) using pandas. I cannot use other libraries to check the sheet visibility. Since, I shall be do more changes if I change the library.

Comment: What do you mean by visibility? Do you just want to check columns and values, like you would see in Excel?

Comment: No, I need to check the excel sheet is hidden.

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625728/openpyxl-check-if-worksheet-is-hidden

Comment: I want to use , pandas. Since, I am using xlsb file.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can see if the sheet is hidden or not

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('file_name.xlsb')

sheets = xls.book.sheets()

for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet.name, sheet.visibility)
```

Comment: It doen;t support xlsb file