# How to ignore hidden folders in python?

Tags: python

How to ignore hidden folders from `os.scandir()` in Python 3.10.x?

```
import os

for dir in os.scandir('C:/'):
    print(dir.path)
```

I don't want these paths.

[image]

I want these paths.

[image]

Comment: For windows, I think this solution answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063074/13944524

Comment: read the docs [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/)

Comment: Several folders are in both the "I want" and "I don't want" screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

This post is for hidden files but it should work for folders as well:
[Cross platform hidden file detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284115/cross-platform-hidden-file-detection)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the folder which contains 1 hidden folder and a file. They get ignored in the final output and only non-hidden directories are getting listed:

[image]

```
import os

    if os.name == 'nt':
        import win32api, win32con
    def file_is_hidden(p):
        if os.name== 'nt':
            attribute = win32api.GetFileAttributes(p)
            return attribute & (win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
        else:
            return p.startswith('.') #linux-osx
    file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if not file_is_hidden(f) and os.path.isdir(f)]
    print(file_list)
```

Output:

```
    ['1', '2']
```